# Appending large data files using first few observations

Tags: stata

I am appending in Stata several data sets in a folder using this code:

```
! dir *.dta /a-d /b >"${cleandata}/$year/filelist.txt"

file open myfile using "${cleandata}/$year/filelist.txt", read
file read myfile line

use `line'
save "${outcomedata}/master_$year.dta", replace

file read myfile line

while r(eof)==0 { 
    append using `line'
    file read myfile line
}

file close myfile

save master_data, replace
```

However, I want to try this with the first `10` observations in each `dta` file because I want to make sure that this works before appending every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code as follows:

```
! dir *.dta /a-d /b >"${cleandata}/$year/filelist.txt"

file open myfile using "${cleandata}/$year/filelist.txt", read
file read myfile line

use `line' in 1/10
save master_data

file read myfile line

while r(eof) == 0 {
    use `line' in 1/10, clear
    append using master_data
    save master_data, replace
    file read myfile line
}

file close myfile
```